# Laravel: Can't enable APC-Cache - Method not found

Tags: laravel-5, apc

I try to enable apc-cache on my laravel-project. APC is enabled on server.

My error-log says something like this:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function Illuminate\Cache\apc_fetch()' in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/ApcWrapper.php:30
```

But when I look in the file at line 30 I can't find the error.

```
return $this->apcu ? apcu_fetch($key) : apc_fetch($key);
```

Why the function apc_fetch is interpreted as it runs under a namespace? It's still a normal default function from php/apc-module, right? Or better, it should be, dont know why not...

Found out this error only appears on live-server. On my dev-Server everything works fine. So it should be a server-misconfiguration.

But I checked everything. The module is enabled and the function "apc_fetch" is defined on the live-server....

And a short-test (explained on php.net) also works fine

```
$bar = 'BAR';
apc_store('foo', $bar);
var_dump(apc_fetch('foo'));
```

Hope you understand the problem.

cheers,
vanderb

Comment: How are you running the "short-test"? Does it work if you put this code in Laravel's index.php?

Comment: If i add the snippet from above to Laravel's index.php works fine. I think something is going wrong with this namespace. But why on live-serve but not on dev-server? Is there any setting i forget for the namespacing?